# Do you only have to pay the reciprocity fee once per passport?

Tags: us-citizens, fees-and-charges, chile, scl

So I just arrived in Santiago this afternoon, and wouldn't you know it... my passport was the wrong color.  So I trudged over to the desk to pay the reciprocity fee.

I noticed that the person who processed the payment stapled a receipt to the last page of my passport.

I thought that was a little odd, so I looked more closely at the receipt:

> VALIDO HASTA LA EXPIRACION DEL PASAPORTE

(valid until the passport expiration date)

Am I interpreting that correctly to mean that I now no longer have to pay the reciprocity fee when I arrive at SCL airport with this passport?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good question, and yes, you are correct.  A few things to understand:

1. The Entry Reciprocity Fee is ONLY charged at SCL.  It applies (differently) to citizens of Albania, Australia, Canada, the United States, and Mexico.
2. Other citizens don't have to pay.  (Yay for the Kiwi passport!)
3. The receipt for payment of the reciprocity fee is attached to your passport. On subsequent visits to Chile, you don’t have to pay the fee again for the life of your passport. When you get a new passport, you’ll have to pay the fee again.

Source: I have found [**several**](http://milepoint.com/forums/threads/chile-and-argentina-reciprocity-fees-for-dummies.8431/) [**sources**](http://milepoint.com/forums/threads/chile-and-argentina-reciprocity-fees-for-dummies.8431/) of [**travellers who have**](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2152366)  done this and [**written about it**](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111216202238AAaxaaM), as well as asking a US friend who has done it a couple of times.